# Displaying the list files should not change the position

Tags: android

I am hiding the title bar in my main activity and filling the full screen with the background image.
I am having another listview activity. This activity will display the list of files. i want to hide the title bar in this activity also. But i dont want to fill the parent with the lists completely. Instead I want to add a background image which will have the header and from below the image header I want to display the list of file items.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

For the `ListActivity`, your XML layout should look like:

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MyListActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/my_background_image"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:id ="@+id/mylist"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And I dont really understand what you mean by "Displaying the list files should not change the position".